# Problem with get_posts, tax_query and counting the number of posts

Tags: get-posts, count, tax-query

I want to count the number of posts that has simoultaneously 3 different taxonomies. THe code i'm using is this:

```
$products = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'products',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'collection',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array($current_collection),
            'operator' => 'IN'
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'type',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array($current_type),
            'operator' => 'IN'
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'color',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array($current_type),
            'operator' => 'IN'
        )
    )   
));
$countpost = count($products);
```

The problem occours when the **colors** and **type** taxonomy term I'm looking for do not exists...

- if the **collection** does not exists, the count is 0
- if the **type** does not exists, it returns posts with the specified collection and color
- it the **color** does not exists, it returns posts with the specified collection and type

what I was expenting, since the relation is AND, was that if one of the terms does not exists, the count should be always 0, instead of basically ignoring that term and considering only tho other two...

am I doing something wrong? how can I fix it?

thanks a lot!

Comment: let me know if it works without these parameters,I need similar functions to implement

Comment: nope, it's not working either... :(

Answer (score 1):

Try this again removing operator and relation arguments as follows: here is a useful link http://ottopress.com/2010/wordpress-3-1-advanced-taxonomy-queries/

```
$products = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'products',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'collection',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array($current_collection)
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'type',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array($current_type)
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'color',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array($current_type)
        )
    )   
));
$countpost = count($products);
```

Comment: nope, not working either. even if I remove operators and relations the result is always the same: if the value of the color or the type does not exist in the database, it simply ignore that part and return all the posts, instad of 0 (no posts).

Comment: will you please explain about all three taxonomies used here? It worked for me where my taxonomies were post category and post tags. what are 'collection', 'type' and 'color'?

Comment: collections are group of products, imagine it like a car brand, type is like the model of the car, and color obviously is a color of the single product (that can come in different colors)

Comment: You simply forgot the `compare` arg.